# Identifying the class type for arguments required in gerDeclaredMethod in java

Tags: java, class, reflection

I am using Java Reflection to invoke a method xyz with these 4 parameter types:

```
Set<LineItems> 
String
Document
Profiler
```

While using getDeclaredMethod I am required to give the method argument type. If String's argument type is String.class, what should be done for `Set<LineItems>`? Should it be Set.class? (Keeping in mind that Set is an interface)

The function xyz is a default function in interface abc. This interface is being implemented in multiple other classes, so method should be reflected here only. Here is my code:

```
Class c = abc.getClass();

Class args[] = new Class[4];
args[0] = Set.class;
args[1] = String.class;
args[2] = Document.class;
args[3] = Profiler.class;

Method m = c.getMethod("xyz",args) ;
```

I'm getting the NoSuchMethodFoundException
I know there could be multiple flaws in this. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by :

```
Object[] args= new Object[4];
args[0]= setOfItems;
args[1]= aString;
args[2]= document;
args[3]= profiler;

Method m = this.getClass().getMethod("xyz", Set.class, String.class, Document.class, Profiler.class);
Object result = proxy.invoke(m, this, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

> what should be done for `Set<LineItems>?`

What you have there `Set.class` should do. Remember that Java generics come with [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), therefore, at **runtime**, the signature of that method will say `Set.class`, too!

And yes, when the **signature** of the method you intend to call says Set, then using the Set (interface) class is exactly what you have to do. If for example, the method signature said `HashSet` then `Set.class` would **not** do!